# How to simplify an npm dashboard

Tags: css, dashboard

I am doing a project in my server. I am searching a simple dashboard to use in a project. I found a free coreui.io (https://coreui.io/demo/4.0/free/docs.html) dashboard. I works great when i run npm. But it's combined with so many part, thats its hard to master. How can I simplify it ? I mean I want 1 css file, 1 js file and htmls. Why ? well its easy to handle it when everything is in one place. (hate sass...) So is there a way to do so ? Or maybe someone knows simple but simmilar free (of not so expensive) dashboards.